# Class definition copy-generation in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, proxy, code-generation, wrapper

I have an assembly (DLL) created from the Early bound classes of dynamcis crm's code genaration tool. These classes mostly have properties.

I want to use these classes as Model with additional control.

Like in java, is was looking forward to use reflection, but could not find example on it or introspection using FxCop

I tried using T4 toolbox (Decorator classes - [here](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/how-to-use-t4-to-generate-decorator-classes/)) but that does not support Properties.
I also tried tools like CodeSmith but could not figure out if that is possible.

I was expecting Visual Studio or its extenstion should be easily do it.

**Original Class**

```
public class Product {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Generated class**

```
public class ProducModel {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Maintainibility:** If original class changes, would your suggested tool/method cope with that?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using "Go to Definition" (F12) feature of visual studio & copy/pasting the required properties.

Detailed answer on [MS Forum](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/03c6bcbd-e730-4eec-9c11-e4b2a5704534)